# NSFetchedResultController limiting fetch count

Tags: controller, request, limit, fetch

If I initialize my NSFetchedResultController with a fetchRequest with a fetchLimit of 20, do I need to call performFetch any additional times if my user scrolls past the first 20 results? Or will performFetch be called for me automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `fetchLimit`, it will not update, but if you want first 20 result, and auto update for more, you can use `setBatchSize` to `20`.

See below for detail:

The count of the fetchedObjects array might not what you want to do, since it does not update the changes from the persistent store. From NSFetchedResultsController documentation:

> The results array only includes instances of the entity specified by the fetch request (fetchRequest) and that match its predicate. (If the fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all instances of the entity specified by the fetch request.)
>
> The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store. The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.

If you only want to fetch 20 objects, set the fetch limit of the NSFetchRequest. If you want only to keep 20 objects in memory, use setBatchSize of the NSFetchRequest object.